# Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds

Tags: protractor

I am new to Protractor and have been trying to run end to end test. I have tried other respondent but still i am getting the above error

**My protractor conf.js looks like this**:

```
directConnect: true,
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
showColors: true,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
getPageTimeout: 30000,
print: function() {}
},
```

**spec.js looks like this**

```
describe('b2-bportral standardOrder', function () {
let onlineOrderPage: OnlineOrderPage;
let loginPage: LoginPage

beforeEach(() => {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();;
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    loginPage.navigateTo();
    loginPage.setUserName("canon@gmail.com");
    loginPage.setPassword("a");
    loginPage.loginClick();
    onlineOrderPage = new OnlineOrderPage();
    onlineOrderPage.navigateTo();
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
it('Standard Order', () => {
    onlineOrderPage.setPartnerName("");

});
});
```

**po.ts looks like this :**

```
export class LoginPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('#/login',30000);
  }
  setUserName(username:string) {
    element(by.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
  }
  setPassword(password:string) {
    element(by.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
  }
  loginClick(){
      return element(by.className("login")).click();
  }

}

export class OnlineOrderPage {
    navigateTo() {
         browser.get('url',30000);
    }
     setPartnerName(value:string){
        element(by.id('selPartnerName')).click();
        return element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'CANON MIDLE EAST')).click();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
b2-bportral standardOrder
× Standard Order
- Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
- Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="selPartnerName"])
```

Anyone please guide me

Comment: Try setting the config option `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true`.  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Answer (score 1):

Protractor tries to load your page, but it timeouts before it can fully load it. There are two possiblities. First make sure you specified correct URL for your page and that your page actually starts to load before timeouting.

Secondly you can increase the timeout for loading page (default is 10) in two ways:

1. In your configuration file set `getPageTimeout: 30000` to increase
   timeout for every `browser.get()`
2. Specify timeout for each individual function with parameter, for
   example: `browser.get("url", 30000);` Note that `browser.driver.get()` uses only 1 parameter, so be sure to use `browser.get()`.

Also if above solutions don't work for you, you may want to try setting timeout for webdriver. You can set it in configuration file with this line: `allScriptsTimeout: 30000`

All values are in milliseconds

EDIT:
First of all put `browser.pause()` and when it pauses look at the browser and see if element with id `selPartnerName` really exists.
If it exists try waiting for it longer with this code:

```
var el = element(by.id('selPartnerName'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 30000);
```

Comment: Hi @FCin, I have specified the correct URL, because on running the Test case it is redirected correctly to that page and stops for a few seconds before the error. Now i have changed set the timeout for every broser as you said, but still the error persists. Please help

Comment: And what about those timeouts? Do they work for you? Use `getPageTimeout` and `allScriptsTimeout`.

Comment: I have done changes in the conf.js for timeout and I think, the timeouts are working fine but the its not finding out the element in the page, any suggestions

Comment: Update your question with more information. I don't understand what element you can't find.

Comment: tried the above method, but not able to get a result. Is there any other solution which would help

Comment: Is your page written in Angular? If your page isn't written in Angular then you have to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;` before running your tests

Comment: Yes the page is written in Angular 2

Comment: And you timeout is still 11 seconds?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I can't understand. And i am stuck because of this error, i can't proceed further. This happens every time when i am redirecting from the login page to any other page.

Comment: I doubt that it will change anything, but you don't need `return` in `return browser.get('#/login',30000);`

Comment: is there way to find an element while redirecting to other page

Comment: Protractor looks into HTML, so as long as your html has element you are looking for, you can use it.